# XCode 3.2 Active SDK. Iphone Simulator 1.0(missing)

Tags: xcode, simulator, xcode3.2

Sorry for my English.
I have installed 3.2 version of XCode on my Mac.
I am using a old version of Xcode because we have an old Mac computer.
I don´t know why, Xcode says:  "Iphone simulator 1.0 (missing)"
Someone knows where is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you download the iOS SDK (for his version it might have  been called iPhone SDK). Also you might want to know that you need at least Xcode 5.1.1 if you want to submit app to Apple and use the latest hardware.

Comment: You can download the full SDK for iOS 4.3 and Xcode 3.2.5 here : https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode